# Polynomial regression - differences between algorithms

Tags: algorithms, regression

I know that I can find a polynomial regression's coefficients doing $(X'X)^{-1}X'y$ (where $X'$ is the transpose).

This is a way of finding them; now, there is (as far as I know) at least one other way, which is by minimizing a cost function using gradient descent. The former method seems to be the easiest to implement ( I did it in C++, I have the latter in Matlab ).

What I wanted to know is the advantage of one of these methods over the other. Upon a particular dataset, with very few points, I found that I couldn't find a satisfactory solution  using $(X'X)^{-1}X'y$, but gradient descent worked fine and I could get an estimation function that made sense. It was 6th degree polynom though, but in this particular case I don't care overfitting the data.

So what's wrong with the matrix resolution over gradient descent ?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but any basic statistics tool allows you to do ordinary least squares (OLS). Doing the matrix inversion manually is quite unnecessary (in particular since computing standard errors and confidence intervals is even more tedious if done by hand).